# Selective ordering in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Most questions about advanced ordering involve a few prioritized fields, but here's a different problem.

I have a series of projects ordered by title, and these projects are assigned to individuals in the company. I want to be able to have each individual's projects **float to the top** for that individual.

This is not a request to order by `assigned_individual` then `job_title` (because this would mess up the ordering of all projects that aren't mine). This is a request to have records still ordered principally by `job_title` but to have an override such that records with, let's say, `assigned_individual_id = 3` are shown first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not hard, you just have to slip a CASE into your ORDER BY to manually push the rows of interest to the top, something like this:

```
id = M.send(:sanitize_sql, ['?', id])
M.order("case when assigned_individual = #{id} then 0 else 1 end, job_title")
```

where, of course, `id` is the user that you want on top. If this is done inside one of M's methods then you won't need to use `send` to get around the protectedness of `sanitize_sql`.

This technique can easily be extended to push multiple users to the top if that's needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do we need that first line? What does the send/sanitize_sql give us that we don't get from something like `id = M.find(5)`?

Comment: @sscirrus: `M.find(5)` gives you an object, interpolating an object into a string probably won't give you the SQL you want. You need the `sanitize_sql` call to properly escape the `id` for inclusion in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Build it in 2 passes:

```
@projects = current_user.projects
@projects += Project.all
@projects.uniq!
```

NB: I assume you have used default scope to order the projects by name.